# Vue 2 / Vue CLI 3: Creating async single file components

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-router, vue-cli-3

I used Vue-CLI 3 and told it that I want to use vue-router.  It generates this type of Webpack import statement in the created routes.js.

```
// route level code-splitting
// this generates a separate chunk (about.[hash].js) for this route
// which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ './views/About.vue')
```

I proceeded to create four views.  Some views call components inside.

```
Home.vue (Home page and default route at '/')
About.vue
Contact.vue
Photos.vue
```

I have made About, Contact, and Photos asynchronous in routes.js

```
import Home from './views/Home.vue';

/* name = named routes */
export const routes = [
    {
        path: '/',
        component: Home,
        name: 'home'
    },
    {
        path: '/photo/:id',
        // component: Photo,
        component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "Photo" */ './views/Photo.vue'),
        name: 'photo'
    },
    {
        path: '/about',
        component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "About" */ './views/About.vue'),
        // component: About,
        name: 'about'
    },
    {
        path: '/contact',
        // component: Contact,
        component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "Contact" */ './views/Contact.vue'),
        name: 'contact'
    },
    {
        /* Wildcard path to catch all other paths */
        path: '*',
        redirect: '/'
    }
];
```

When I do a build, Vue CLI does create additional JS and CSS chunks (about.[hash].js, etc.).  However, when I load the Home route, these other chunks are loaded according to Chrome's devtools, but there is also nothing in the response tab.  Then, when I visit About, Contact, or Photo routes, the browser loads those chunks, but now there is now something in the response tab.

Is async working as intended?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I might have figured out what these extra calls on my Home route are.
Webpack has a config where prefetching can be turned on.  I guess Vue CLI's or Webpack's default is to have the prefetch turned on.

https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#prefetching-preloading-modules

https://medium.com/webpack/link-rel-prefetch-preload-in-webpack-51a52358f84c

Somebody on the Vue forums pointed to the Vue-CLI documentation to me: 
 https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#prefetch